# The design guidelines, I should follow while designing UI for android smart devices?

Tags: html, android-layout, css, user-interface, photoshop

Since I am a beginner as far as designing for android smart devices are concern, I would like to know about, **the Design Guidelines, I should follow while designing UI for android smart devices. Here I meant Photoshop design Guidelines & HTML5/CSS3 guidelines.**

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice would be to follow the official Android Design Guidelines by Google. You can find them [here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Besides that, there are loads of GUI kits you can download from different sources that contain Android design elements.